# Assign Firebase Cloud Message Token to new java variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to android development, but I am confused about the following situation. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging which allows the app to create a token. I can create the token, but I want to assign the value of that token to the `key` variable as shown in the code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public String key = "None";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("myTag", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        key = token;
                   }
                });
        Log.d("myTag", key);
    }
}
```

However, it does not work as `key` only outputs the initial string that I assigned it "None". So I was wondering how I can extract the value of the token and assign it to another variable?

My ultimate goal is to get the token value so I can create a QR code from it.
Thanks

Comment: Does `Log.d("myTag", key)` says that it always `None` value?

Comment: Yup. I had initialized it as "None", and it printed "None" even after I had set ```key=token```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you said at the comment, yes the value will become null when you put the log outside from the method `onComplete`. Firebase does not work like that. You have to put the `Log` inside the method `onComplete`.

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("myTag", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        key = token;
                        Log.d("myTag", key); //Here
                   }
                });
```

Comment: I guess Firebase just does not let you push values outside the block. I was planning on using the token outside of the Firebase part so I can use its value to create a qr code. But since Firebase wont let me do that, I imagine I would just need to place the generate qr code function inside the Firebase block.

Comment: @JeffBoker yes you can try do that

Comment: @JeffBoker you can press 'right' icon if I already answered your question. Thank you